# Running Multiple call stacks/apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I've made a bot/app in visual studio code and Node JS and it runs fine,  but i have other projects I need to relaunch as well while keeping the current one running. I remember having this problem years ago called pm2, thought it was pretty useful, but as i recall the bug problem was while it could relache the app if it crashed so it stayed up 24/7 i didn't have acess to the console log which i use to track the topic that trigers my app, the user name who triggered it and the response. Anyone familiar with PM2 or another program that would retain the console for each running app?

Edit: found some info via
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

theres even a web app you can set up to run your app
https://app.pm2.io/

but as of yet i haven't found a way to easily monitor the console.log output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so near as i can tell the best way to monitor the console long va the web app is with

```
console.log(`log`);
```

As this works flawlessly with my discord js bot, however my reddit bot doesnt seem to use it so it may be API specific on what can pass/use Console.log